# SQL: selecting unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
select
    id,
    attempt,
    question,
    att_number,
    answer,
    timestamp,
    event
from
    mytable
```

gives me this output in MSSQL 2008 R2:

```
id,attempt,question,seq_number,answer,timestamp,event
1296040,22059,3813,0,"11960,11961,11959,11958:",1265006717,0
1296165,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011083,2
1296166,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011049,6
1296163,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011037,6
1296164,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011072,6
```

How do I select just the unique rows for the attempt, question, att_number, answer and event columns with the LOWEST value for the timestamp column?

I want this:

```
id,attempt,question,seq_number,answer,timestamp,event
1296040,22059,3813,0,"11960,11961,11959,11958:",1265006717,0
1296165,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011083,2
1296163,22059,3813,1,"11960,11961,11959,11958:11960",1265011037,6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
with cte as(
    select id,attempt,question,att_number,answer,timestamp,event,
           rn = Row_Number() Over (
                    Partition By attempt, question, att_number, answer,event 
                    Order By timestamp Asc)
    from mytable
)
select select,id,attempt,question,att_number,answer,timestamp,event
from cte
where rn = 1
```

If you want all records with the lowest timestamp per group replace `Row_Number` with `Dense_Rank`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `group by` clause.

Below `select` statement will work for your example.

```
select        
    min(id), attempt,question,
    att_number, answer, timestamp,
    event
from
    mytable
group by 
    attempt,question,
    att_number, answer, timestamp,
    event
```

But if you really want to the lowest timestamp, you have to  remove `id` column form `select` as below

```
select         
    attempt,question,
    att_number, answer, min(timestamp),
    event
from
    mytable
group by 
    attempt,question,
    att_number, answer,
    event
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question -> 'with the LOWEST value for the timestamp column"

Comment: @MitchWheat Thats true, but we can't gruop by id column

Comment: Yes, id is the identity column.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use GROUP BY with MIN:

```
select MIN(id),
       attempt,
       question,
       seq_number,
       answer,
       MIN(timestamp),
       event
  from mytable
  GROUP BY ATTEMPT, QUESTION, SEQ_NUMBER, ANSWER, EVENT
```

It's not obvious from the question, but OP wants both MIN(ID) and MIN(TIMESTAMP).  Also note that the column names in the example results are NOT the same as the ones in the OP's SQL.  I chose to accept that the `seq_number` in the example results are the same as `att_number` from the original SELECT statement.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8d42/5).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
id,
attempt,
question,
att_number,
answer,
timestamp,
event
from
mytable m 
where m.timestamp=(
    select min(timestamp) 
    from mytable mi 
    where mi.attempt=m.attempt and mi.question=m.question and mi.att_number=m.att_number and mi.answer=m.answer and mi.event=m.event
)
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages of using a sub-query like in this answer?

Answer (score -1):

use distinct and order by statement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Shai Your comment is wrong.  This is a worthy suggestion, but to make it a _real answer_, I would suggest actually providing the SQL and not simply suggesting the course.